# Initialization of UIDocumentPickerViewController in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerviewcontroller, ios14

I have a `UIDocumentPickerViewController` that picks only images. This works fine in iOS 13:

```swift
let supportedTypes: [String] = ["public.image"]
let documentPickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: supportedTypes, in: .import)
```

I'm trying to achieve the same in iOS 14.

However, `init(documentTypes:in:)` was deprecated in iOS 14.0.

So I'm assuming I have to use this initializer instead: `init(forOpeningContentTypes:asCopy:)`

The `forOpeningContentTypes` argument expects an array of `UTType`.
I'm not sure how to use / import it.
Is it like `[UTType.Image]`?

```swift
let supportedTypes: [UTType] = [UTType.Image]
self.viewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: supportedTypes, asCopy: true)
```

This won't even compile because `Cannot find type 'UTType' in scope`.
I also tried `import MobileCoreServices` and even `import CoreServices`, but that didn't help.

The documentation [for the new Document Picker initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller/3566733-init) points to this [UTTypeReference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttypereference) -- so I tried using that, but it can't be found either.

How can I have a `UIDocumentPickerViewController` that picks only images in iOS 14?

> Update

This works (thanks @Warren):

```swift
import UniformTypeIdentifiers
let supportedTypes: [UTType] = [UTType.image]
let pickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: supportedTypes, asCopy: true)
```

Comment: You need `UniformTypeIdentifiers` framework for UTType

Comment: @WarrenBurton if you write an answer, I could accept it.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Add  `import UniformTypeIdentifiers` to your swift file to get access to `UTType`

See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers) for more usages.

And the [WWDC2020 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10039/) "Build document-based apps in SwiftUI" for a practical demo.

Comment: It's ridiculous that Apple doesn't import `UniformTypeIdentifiers` in `UIDocumentPickerViewController`'s declaration.

Comment: How would one know this from looking here

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttypereference

just curious, thanks.

Comment: Inference and the UT namespace. The documentation references UTType as a core type and when you look up UTType you can see it’s a member of that module. Not easy for a person to get a direct answer however.