# How to upload a file to Firebase in an iOS app (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I used this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64168754/16212254 for reference to allow the user to pick a file, but now I am stuck on how to upload the file to Firebase.
I'm NEW to Swift, please don't mind my silly question.

I tried to follow https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#ios and https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files but still could not figure out how to send the file to firebase since I don't know the attached file's name and path.

Comment: Can you check [this](https://handyopinion.com/utility-class-to-upload-images-videos-files-to-firebase-storage-in-swift-ios/) article

Answer (score 2):

The answer you used to be able to pick a file works fine, but doesn't give a reference to the selected image or file outside the scope of the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` and `didPickDocumentsAt` functions.

Here's how to save your file/image data to be able to access it later.

- Create a variable of type `Data?` in your ViewController.

  `var myData: Data?`
- If you are dealing with an Image, inside the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` function, save the png data of the selected image inside the newly created variable (which scope is not limited to the functions itself). If you are instead dealing with a file, do basically the same thing inside the `didPickDocumentAt` function.

```
// Image
if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
    // The following 2 lines don't actually do anything: the selectedImageData dictionary
    // ceases existing as soon as the functions ends
    // selectedImageData["filename"] = fileUrl.lastPathComponent
    // selectedImageData["data"] = pickedImage.pngData()?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)

    self.myData = pickedImage.pngData()
}

// File
do {
    let fileData = try Data.init(contentsOf: file.absoluteURL)
    // The following 2 lines don't actually do anything: the selectedFileData dictionary
    // ceases existing as soon as the functions ends
    // selectedFileData["filename"] = file.lastPathComponent
    // selectedFileData["data"] = fileData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)

    self.myData = fileData
} catch {
    // ...
}
```

Then, to upload the data to the Firebase Storage, you can use the following function:

```swift
import FirebaseStorage // At the beginning of the file

// Uploads the selected image/file data there is any.
func uploadSavedData() {
    guard let data = myData else { return } // Checks whether there is actual data to upload.

    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
    let fileRef = storageRef.child("userUID/files/documentName.png")

    let uploadTask = fileRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in 
        guard let metadata = metadata else { return } // Cancels task if there is any error
        
        fileRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in {
            guard let downloadURL = url else { return }
            print(downloadURL) // Prints the URL to the newly uploaded data.
        }
    }
}
```

**Further resources on the topic**

- [Official Firebase Storage documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files) (it's very well-written)
- [How to choose an image with UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25514262/17026411)
- [How to upload data to Firebase Storage and the URL to Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44061967/17026411)
- [Scope and Context in Swift](https://learnappmaking.com/scope-context-swift-how-to/)